# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, swing, exception, cmd, classpath

I have problem running the code in CMD

```
public class Testing
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws TestingFormatException, IOException
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filename = scanner.nextLine();

    File input = new File(filename);
    FileReader fileInput = new FileReader(input);

    TestingIo file = new TestingReaderWriter();
    file.read(fileInput);
    }
}
```

both classes and java files are in same directory

```
C:\testing\Testing.java

C:\testing\Testing.class

C:\testing\test.txt
```

Here are the following command I key in:

```
C:\testing> javac Testing.java
C:\testing> java Testing > test.txt
```

it show me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: # Show contents 
(The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:55)
        at Mipsim.main(Mipsim.java:22)
```

But when I key in this command there is no error:

```
C:\testing> javac Testing.java
C:\testing> java Testing 
C:\testing> test.txt


CLASSPATH is set to .;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin
```

Test.txt

# Show contents
   test1
   test2

May I know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You mean `java Testing < test.txt`, right? What does the test.txt file contain? Its first line, that your class reads, is `# Show contents`, right? Do you have a file named `# Show contents`in this directory? I guess not.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a short but *complete* example - the code you've got doesn't compile at the moment because it refers to a class you don't provide the code for.

Comment: Indeed - if you run `java Testing > test.txt` then it waits for your input.

Comment: inside my test.txt is
# Show contents
test1
test2

Comment: The tag `swing` is the most important one. Luckily you edited your post to add it.

Comment: Also, the bin directory of the JDK should not be in the CLASSPATH. In fact. CLASSPATH is supposed to contain directories and jar files containing classes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the command you're executing is in fact

```
java Testing < test.txt
```

This basically means: execute the `Testing` class, and, when reading from `System.in`, don't read what the user enters, but what is inside the test.txt file.

Since your test.text file contains `# Show contents`, and since your class reads one line from System.in and treats that as a file name, it effectively tries to read from a file named `# Show contents`, which doesn't exist, hence the exception.